# c# mysql - update field value to include \r\n using mySqlParameter

Tags: c#, mysql, newline

I'm trying to update a column in a row with a new value. the new value is in a variable, and the value contain a new line in it.
This method receive as dictionary the column name and values need to change, and create a dynamic update command.

The Code is working for any other row in the table, but when a newline is involved, and SQL Error saying: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near

```
var valueStr = "";
for (var i = 0; i < srcRow.Count; i++)
{
    valueStr += string.Format("{0} = ?prm{1}", srcRow.Keys.ElementAt(i),i);
    if (i < srcRow.Count - 1)
          valueStr += ", ";


var query = string.Format("UPDATE {0} SET {1} WHERE {2}", table, valueStr, pkey);

try
{
    using (var cmd = destConn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = query;
        for (int i = 0; i < srcRow.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?prm" + i.ToString(),srcRow.Values.ElementAt(i));
        }
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
 }
```

Thanks
Shimshon

Comment: What's the value in variable `query`?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `\r\n` with `\\r\\n`,

MySQL receive it and it will escape to database.